# Insert value into database only when the Switchbutton changes

Tags: android

I'm using a switchbutton to send informations to my sqlite database.

When the Switchbutton is ON, inserts a value into a table, when the Switchbutton is OFF, deletes the same value.

The problem is that, when I check the switchbutton, the value is sent, but when I close the switchbutton activity, and I come back, the record is inserted again, because the switchbutton appears ON.

I would like to prevent this from checking if the value that I am going to send, already exists in the table.

Here my code:

```
public void checkFavorite(){

    sbFavorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            Favorites test = new Favorites(globalVar.getSessionUserId(), Integer.valueOf(splitExtras(LOCATION_ID)));

            if(isChecked) {

                if (!connect.getAllFavorites().contains(test)){
                    connect.addFavorites(test);

            }

            }else{


                if (connect.getAllFavorites().contains(test)){
                    connect.deleteFavorites(test);

                }


            }

        }
    });


    sbFavorite.setChecked(Boolean.valueOf(splitExtras(LOCATION_FAVORITE)));

}
```

The line: Boolean.valueOf(splitExtras(LOCATION_FAVORITE))

Receives a boolean value from my database, it checks if the value that was sent is inserted into the table, returns false when this value doesn't exist.

Comment: try it using `insertWithOnConflict`

Comment: I don't think that the problem is on sqlite, btw I tried to follow your suggestion but It didn't solved the problem. But thanks.